# Images not showing after deployment with Passenger/Capistrano to Nginx server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, capistrano, asset-pipeline, passenger

Hi I'm deploying my first Rails app to Ubuntu 16 server using `Capistrano` everything went smooth except the images are not showing in the production environment.

On the production server the images are located in this path : `/myapp/current/public/assets`

But if I look at this in the browser my broken images links gives me this(see picture), this is a broken link for the header image.

[image: broken images]

the strange thing is that there is a `.svg`file in the `/myapp/current/public/assets` which is showing up perfectly in the browser, In the picture below is the path shown 
 [image: svg file]

this is my `Capfile`

```
# Load DSL and set up stages
 require "capistrano/setup"

# Include default deployment tasks
require "capistrano/deploy"


set :rbenv_type, :user # or :system, depends on your rbenv setup
set :rbenv_ruby, '2.3.1'


require 'capistrano/rbenv'

require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rails'


# Load custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks` if you have any defined
Dir.glob("lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake").each { |r| import r }
```

This is the `config/deploy.rb`

```
# config valid only for current version of Capistrano
lock '3.6.1'

set :application, 'myapp'
set :repo_url, 'git@github.com:DadiHall/myapp.git'


 # Default deploy_to directory is /var/www/my_app_name
 set :deploy_to, '/home/deploy/myapp'


 set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml config/secrets.yml}
 set :linked_dirs, %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}

 namespace :deploy do

 desc 'Restart application'
 task :restart do
  on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
   execute :touch, release_path.join('tmp/restart.txt')
  end
 end

 after :publishing, 'deploy:restart'
 after :finishing, 'deploy:cleanup'
```

end

Here is the `environments/production.rb`

```
Rails.application.configure do

config.cache_classes = true
config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier


 # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
 config.assets.compile = false

 config.assets.digest = true
 config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false

 # `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved to config/initializers/assets.rb


 config.log_level = :debug

 config.i18n.fallbacks = true

 config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

 config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

 config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false

Braintree::Configuration.environment = :sandbox
Braintree::Configuration.merchant_id = ENV['merchant_id']
Braintree::Configuration.public_key = ENV['public_key']
Braintree::Configuration.private_key = ENV['private_key']

end
```

In the `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` I have following lines

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    server_name mydomain.com;
    passenger_enabled on;
    rails_env    production;
    root         /home/deploy/myapp/current/public;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }
}
```

this is the nginx Error log

```
 [ 2016-09-28 06:25:02.4500 1594/7f900ee89700 age/Sha/ApiServerUtils.h:794 ]:  Log file reopened.
 [ 2016-09-28 09:45:43.7508 1597/7f2326502700 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:819 ]:   Checking whether to disconnect long-running connections for process 1978,  application /home/deploy/hlinreykdal/current/public (production)
App 21337 stdout: 
App 21405 stdout: 
[ 2016-09-28 10:30:31.0631 1597/7f2326502700 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:819 ]:  Checking whether to disconnect long-running connections for process 21405,  application /home/deploy/hlinreykdal/current/public (production)
App 23240 stdout: 
App 23308 stdout: 
[ 2016-09-28 10:41:40.1769 1597/7f2326502700 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:819 ]: Checking whether to disconnect long-running connections for process 23308, application /home/deploy/hlinreykdal/current/public (production)
App 24329 stdout: 
App 24397 stdout:
```

I have tried `bundle exec rake assets precompile` with out any luck.

I have deployed and restarted `nginx` again and again, with out any luck

I have tried almost every answer to similar questions here on stack overflow, but nothing seems to work.

Am I missing something here?

I'm sure this problem has something to do with the assets pipeline, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Can anyone please take a look at this and advise me.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok if anyone is experiencing a similar problem you might want to check out the `config.assets.compile` In my case I only had to change the config/environments/production.rb  `config.assets.compile` from  `false`, I changed it to `true` and now everything worked.... It only took me two days to figure it out :D

Comment: Where we change this from false to true ? in config file or where ? i am also stuck in this

Answer (score 1):

Note that `public/assets` is where the asset pipeline puts its stuff. If this is for static assets, I would put them in `app/assets/images` in order to use the asset pipeline, or choose another directory name.

Comment: How can I do that on the server? I mean, how can I do that during the deploy to the server?

Comment: You change your source tree or your deployment processes to account for it. Your capistrano process is already linking public/system, so I'd just use that.

Comment: Ok thanks, I get it , but I don´t get it :) Were and how can I change the source tree?

Comment: Ok the Joke is on me in the `config/environments/production.rb`the `config.assets.compile` was set to `false`, I changed it to `true`and now everything is working smoothly :)

Answer (score 1):

I was using html's img tag to serve image assets as following

`<img src="/assets/AdminLTELogo.png" alt="AdminLTE Logo" class="brand-image im">`

Just had to change it to following and it worked.

`<%= image_tag 'AdminLTELogo.png' , alt: "AdminLTE Logo", class: "brand-image im %>`

Cheers.